# Applied texture appears transparent when loading in ThreeJs

Tags: texturing, uv

I am a newbie in blender, just started learning the basics, don't have sound understanding of 3d modeling yet, so I've applied a material texture in blender, but when I'm importing this using ThreeJs that portion of the model just appears transparent in the browser.

In blender it's like the model hand is like this:

[image: model hand]

this part of the model is using an image texture as surface paint

[image: surface paint config]

But when loading this in the browser with ThreeJs

using this snippet:

```
const fbxLoader = new GLTFLoader(manager)
for (const model of Object.values(models)) {
fbxLoader.load(model.url, (fbx) => {
  model.fbx = fbx
  
  if (model.url.indexOf("drum") > -1) {
    model.fbx.name = "drumShiva"
  } else if (model.url.indexOf("shiva") > -1) {
    model.fbx.name = "shiva"
  }

}, undefined, function ( error ) {
  console.error( error );
})
```

}

the result I'm getting is this:

[image: hole in the model]

it appears like a hole, completely transparent

By the way, if someone would be interested to see the url were this is being published, this is the one: (https://krishna-disse.web.app/shiva)

Comment: Maybe make sure normals are pointing outside (Viewport overlays > enable Face Orientation to see if all is blue, if red, recalculate them).

Comment: Hi @MrZak, I´ve done that, and they are all blue. But the hole in the hand still continues. I´m using 'Diffuse BSDF' as material. I wonder if this is accepted standard to be exported in glb file